# How to override PASTE operations in ScintillaNet?

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, paste, scintilla

I am using the Scintilla control from [ScintillaNet](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), and I need to have some control over the paste operations (in order to be able to check some things and/or update the text to be pasted).

I've tried to create a subclass of the Scintilla control and override the WndProc method.
Then, I intercept the WM_PASTE message (0x0302), no luck. I never catch it.

Here is the code I use:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Paste");
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove ScintillaNET's built in CTRL+V handler with:

```
scintilla.Commands.RemoveBinding(Keys.V, Keys.Control, ScintillaNet.BindableCommand.Paste);
```

And add your own CTRL+V handler (menu item?) to do a:

```
ScintillaNet.Selection.Text = your_processed_clipboard_data;
```

That would insert at the current cursor position, or replace the current selection.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm on Ctrl+V && Ctrl+Insert. However, I could not find how to get control over the Paste entry in the right-click context menu.